# Accidentally deleted Ubuntu partition, Windows 8 hibernated, cannot access bios to boot from USB. Help?

Tags: grubrescue

I made a mistake I completely regret. After I deleted my Ubuntu partition in Windows 8, my battery got too low and I lost power. I plugged in the cord and restarted the machine and was hit with a GRUB Rescue screen. I tried rebooting with a Ubuntu recovery USB, (I don't have a cd drive on the machine) and it didn't work. I've noticed after a few attempts to access my BIOS (F7) that the text that states how to access bios has been replaced with "resume from hibernation". I'm stuck in a infinite loop.

How can I resume hibernation into windows through Grub Recovery?

Alternatively, How can I boot from the Ubuntu USB drive from Grub Recovery?

Thanks a million.

Comment: Open BIOS and change the boot priority.May be another key like `del` or `f2`. Consult manual. A hard disk change / OS modification can't affect BIOS. BIOS is readonly from the OS point of view.

Comment: I know for a fact that in order to access the BIOS I had to use F7. Ive tried F1-12 just to be positive and DEL key is unfortunately not helping me either. Thank you for the suggestion anyhow.

Comment: possibly this ?? http://archimedesden.wordpress.com/2011/11/29/windows-hibernate-where-did-my-bios-options-go/

Comment: It looked promising, and I've attempted his method multiple times, I'm still left with windows trying to resume from hibernation. I'm going to purchase a new USB drive and going to install Ubuntu 12.10 on it from a different machine. I tried booting from the USB on a different laptop and nothing was happening.  

The things that's driving me crazy is that I know for sure that the BIOS on my brick was set for USB to be the first in the boot record. Perhaps the USB stick was the problem all along?

Answer (score 0):

In your bios try to tell your computer that you have another hard disk (witch is your USB drive), and then add it to boot devices. That depends on  your bios. During bootup you may need to press <kbd>Del</kbd> or <kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>F1</kbd>, Again this depends on your bios.

In order to make a flash bootable you have some options including using a tool named "unetbootin" witch I believe is the best tool to do so.